# My VB code appends two nodes instead of only one

Tags: xml, vb.net, append

I have the following XML file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Config>
    <ImgFileName>W10-00</ImgFileName>
    <Index>1</Index>
    <Diag>0</Diag>
</Config>
```

And I want to add a new node 'CanSS' and make the value = '1'.

This is the code I am calling

```vb
Private Sub AddNode(ByVal CFGFile As String, ByVal Node As String, ByVal ValStr As String)
    Dim docXMLDOM As DOMDocument
    Dim nodeRoot As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim nodeNewElement As IXMLDOMElement

    ' Initialize the document model
    docXMLDOM = New DOMDocument

    ' Open the XML document
    docXMLDOM.load(CFGFile)

    ' Get a reference to the root node
    nodeRoot = docXMLDOM.documentElement

    nodeNewElement = docXMLDOM.createElement(Node)
    nodeNewElement.text = ValStr
    nodeRoot.appendChild(nodeNewElement)

    ' Save the file
    docXMLDOM.save(CFGFile)

    docXMLDOM = Nothing
End Sub
```

which changes my XML to this

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Config>
    <ImgFileName>W10-00</ImgFileName>
    <Index>1</Index>
    <Diag>0</Diag>
<CanSS>1</CanSS><CanSS>1</CanSS></Config>
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I don't see your problem. There is only one `CanSS` node in the result you posted.

Comment: It looks correct to me also.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is VB you can make use of XElement and XElement literals.

```vb
Private Sub AddNode(CFGFile As String, Node As XElement, ValStr As String)
    'to use this method, note the use of the literal
    '  AddNode("PATH to xml", <CanSS/>, "The value")
    Dim xe As XElement
    Try
        xe = XElement.Load(CFGFile)
        Dim nd As XElement = New XElement(Node)
        nd.Value = ValStr
        xe.Add(nd)
        xe.Save(CFGFile)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'todo Error
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, your code snip works well but oddly the XML file contains two identical nodes afterwards! It's beginning to look like something else is going on!

Comment: @Darryl - if you step through the code in the debugger the code posted should not add two nodes.  I agree something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone! Turns out that some code I was using to gain administrator privileges caused my app to run, close and re-run. I now use the app manifest to elevate privileges, my code only runs once and only one node is created!